# Execute pytest hooks only when test is marked with custom marker

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

So I have custom marker defined in my `pytest.ini` file

```
[pytest]
markers =
    foomark: Mark a test as foo
```

Whenever running a test which is marked with `foomark` I also need the test to be used/executed with a special set of hook script implementations which go into the `conftest.py`.

```
def pytest_foo_hook(request):
    print("This is a foo-marked test.")
```

`pytest.ini` reside in the project root. The `conftest.py` has to be put in each subfolder containing a test/test-suite of the project. The problem with that is, that the tests, which are marked with `foomark` are spread out over multiple packages and for each of those I need to add the hook-implementation, resulting in a lot of boilerplate code. Also defining the hook scripts for all tests is not an option.

Is there a way to actually link the marker with a set of pytest hook scripts to only execute on tests which have been marked with `foomark`?

Comment: Can't you just check for the marker in your hook (using something like `request.node.iter_markers()`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as MrBean Bremen pointed out and also noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59687248/9898968), the request object accessible in each hook script implementation has the markers of the calling test included. When doing this, the hook will be executed for all tests of the suite still but it enables one to filter out the tests, which have the marker `foomark`. For my use case that is sufficient. Simple solution may look like this:

```
def pytest_foo_hook(request):
    for marker in request.node.iter_markers():
        if marker.name == 'foomark':
            print("This is a foo-marked test.")
```